# How to get data from php in JS on a native android app?

Tags: javascript, php, android, ajax, intel-xdk

I'm working on a cross-platform application and I got some troubles with my data.

Actually I have a full website with a lot of php and I'm working with the Intel XDK to make a native application of this website.

But here is the thing, I know I can execute php on my native app, so i'm trying to execute few scripts directly on my server and to take back the result with an ajax request.

Here is the code : (Javascript)

```
var games = location.search;
    var res = games.split("=");

    $.ajax({    //create an ajax request to a page that prints the address.
        url: "http://tonight-app.fr/php/mobile_app/getGamesLists.php",  //url for the address page
        data: {"name": res[1]},
        success: function(result){
            var games = result; //create a variable and give it the value of the response data
            var gamesSplit = games.split(";");
            for(i=0;i<gamesSplit.length;i++){
                var gamesSplit2 = gamesSplit[i].split(",");
                test(gamesSplit2[0]);
            }
        }
    });

    function test(gamesSplit2) {
        console.log(gamesSplit2);
        var ul = document.createElement("ul");
        ul.id = "email-list";
        ul.innerHTML = gamesSplit2;
        document.getElementById('test').appendChild(ul);
    }
```

Here is the php on the server (to this address mention in the url of the ajax)

```
<?php
require_once("connect_database.php");
mysqli_set_charset($con, "utf8");
$name = $_GET["name"];
$sql="SELECT * FROM `games`";
$reponse = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($reponse, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    if ($row[2] == $name) {
        echo $result = '
        <a href="gamesReceipes.php?id=',$row[0],'">
        <li class="unread clickable-row">
            <div class="name">
                ',$row[1],'
            </div>
            <div class="message">
                Voir la préparation
            </div>
        </li>;';
    }
}
echo $result;
?>
```

So to explain, I'm executing my php script which gave me the $result and i'm supposed to display this result in my Ajax.

It's working on the emulator in the Intel XDK but not after when i'm building the app ! (Of course my phone have the 4g activated)

It's supposed to be like this on the display :

[[image: Here is the display[1]]

I hope you can understand my problem here ... Thanks guys !

Comment: I think you will find this is incorrect `mysqli_fetch_array($reponse, MYSQL_NUM)` and should be `mysqli_fetch_array($reponse, MYSQLI_NUM)`

Comment: Doesn't change anything actually.

Comment: It might be a whitelist problem, try looking at this: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/cordova-whitelisting-with-intel-xdk-for-ajax-and-launching-external-apps

Comment: @OldGeeksGuide YES YES YESSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS !!!!! thanks a lot dude, you saved my day ! thanks !

Comment: Hey @OldGeeksGuide : Did you already saw the same problem with a integrate google map ? It doesn't want to display ...

Comment: I was able to successfully get google maps to work, but I had to eliminate one of the meta settings in the header, I think it was the one that starts '<meta name="viewport" . . .', that could have other detrimental effects, but give it a try and see.

Comment: Hey. I found my problem. I didn't put the permission in the xml ... I spend hours and hours on the web for that LOL. But Finaly I got it :) 
Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 1):

By this link :

https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/cordova-whitelisting-with-intel-xdk-for-ajax-and-launching-external-apps

Thanks yo @OldGeeksGuide who gave me this link ! I just had to add the link to my script in the intel xdk and it worked ! Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be trying to echo the same thing twice. returning data to an AJAX call should be done once and the last thing you do in the script.

```
<?php
require_once("connect_database.php");
mysqli_set_charset($con, "utf8");
$name = $_GET["name"];
$sql="SELECT * FROM `games`";
$reponse = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

// init the $result var
$result = '';


// incorrect parameter constant
//while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($reponse, MYSQL_NUM)) {
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($reponse, MYSQLI_NUM)) {
    if ($row[2] == $name) {
        //echo $result = '
        $result .= '
        <a href="gamesReceipes.php?id=' . $row[0] . '">
        <li class="unread clickable-row">
            <div class="name">
                ' . $row[1] . '
            </div>
            <div class="message">
                Voir la préparation
            </div>
        </li>;';
    }
}
echo $result;
?>
```

You could also simplify this.

As you are passing the `name` of the game to this script you could add that to the query as a search criteria like so and then remove a lot of unnecessary processing.

```
<?php
    require_once("connect_database.php");
    mysqli_set_charset($con, "utf8");

    // init the $result var
    $result = '';

    if ( isset($_GET['name'] ) {    
        $name = $_GET["name"];
        $sql="SELECT * FROM `games` WHERE `name` = '$name'";
        $reponse = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

        // I assume there is only one ro w that contains this name
        // so the loop is not required now
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($reponse, MYSQLI_NUM)) {

            $result .= '
                <a href="gamesReceipes.php?id=' . $row[0] . '">
                    <li class="unread clickable-row">
                       <div class="name">' . $row[1] . '</div>
                       <div class="message">Voir la préparation</div>
                    </li>;';
        }
    } else {
        $result = 'No name parameter passed';
    }
    echo $result;
    exit;
?>
```

Comment: I changed it like you, but nothing happen. And even my $result = 'something ...' does not display.

Comment: Hum, in fact I have now a error 500 on the get from Ajax.

Comment: You get 500 with suggestion 1 or suggestion 2

Comment: 1 since I change the echo $result in $result. (Yep when i put back the echo it works)

Comment: Woops, forgot to change the concatenation from `,` to `.` when I removed the `echo` check suggestion 1 again now! Sorry, silly me.

Comment: Yep better. But now I only get 1 result in the echo. (And still nothing on my phone)

Comment: Actually i have like 5/6. But I just put echo $result and delete the echo $result at the end and I have all the result. It's just not displaying on my native app in the phone ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94005/discussion-between-nicolas-lebot-and-riggsfolly).